# How can I fetch JSON from an URL and pass it to a const in react?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch, react-table

I am trying out react-table and am very new to react in general. Right now, in the code below, a local JSON(MOCK_DATA.json) is passed into the const data. I want to replace the local JSON with data fetched from an URL. How can I do that? Thank you :)

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react'
import { useTable, useFilters, useGlobalFilter, usePagination, useSortBy } from 'react-table'
import MOCK_DATA from './MOCK_DATA.json'
import { COLUMNS } from './columns'
import { GlobalFilter } from './GlobalFilter'
import { ColumnFilter } from './ColumnFilter'

export const FilteringTable = () => {
  const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, [])
  const data = useMemo(() => MOCK_DATA, [])
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use http libraries/js API's and set the response in a react state. Simplest is the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState();
     

 fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setData(data));
```

Alternatively, you can use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) which is also great, and my personal favorite.

Note the above example works only for functional components. If you plan to use class components use this.setState() API. When do you want to trigger the API call to your backend server depends on your use case. Most common usecase would be to fetch data on page load. So your app would look like.

```
function App(){
const [data, setData] = React.useState({}); //setting it to empty map as default
React.useEffect(() => {
 fetch('http://your-api/')
      .then(response => setData(response.json())) //setting the response in our data object
      .then(data => console.log(data));
},[]) //called when page is loaded for first time
return (<Table data = {data}/>) // when data is fetched, react re renders the table component since value of data changes.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data with the `Fetch api` and return the data to state with the `useState` hook.

Maybe this links give you some insight for your further research on this topic.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3Px88x_PsA&t=1s (youtube),
- https://blog.logrocket.com/patterns-for-data-fetching-in-react-981ced7e5c56/ (some Article)